# How to give list of inputs in shell script?

Tags: linux, shell, svn

I have a requirement to give a list of inputs in Shell script and read them and iterate and do 'svn update' for each folder like below:

```
    echo "Please give the list of folders to be updated:"
    read $list
    for name in ${list[@]} do
          svn update $name
    done
```

How can i achieve this functionality via shell script.

Thanks and regards,

Raja

Answer (score 3):

If you're trying to read values into an array, use: `read -a`

```
read -a list -p "Please give the list of folders to be updated: "

for name in "${list[@]}"; do
   svn update "$name"
done
```

Otherwise just use like this:

```
read -p "Please give the list of folders to be updated: " list

for name in $list; do
   svn update "$name"
done
```

Though keep in mind your folder names should not have space or newlines for this.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Please give the list of folders to be updated:"
read list $*
for name in "${list[@]}"; do
    svn update "${name}"
done
```